# 4 channel IplImage javacv to android bitmap

Tags: android, opencv, bitmap, javacv, iplimage

I'm trying to record video by checking each frame of camera preview to bitmap with quality ARGB_8888. As it required 4 channel, Created IplImage with channel 4 too. Now the output have two major problems :

1) Bitmap that created from IplImage have grayscale. even if I have converted it from BGR2RGBA.
2) 4 channel IplImage gave me bitmap (divided in 4 parts) with same screen.

Let me put my code over here.

```
    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        if (yuvIplimage != null && recording) {
            videoTimestamp = 1000 * (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);


            // Where imagewidth = 640 and imageheight  = 480 (As per camera preview size)
            // Create the yuvIplimage 

            IplImage yuvimage = IplImage.create(imageWidth, imageHeight * 3 / 2, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 2);
            yuvimage.getByteBuffer().put(data);


            IplImage rgbimage = IplImage.create(imageWidth, imageHeight, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
            opencv_imgproc.cvCvtColor(yuvimage, rgbimage, opencv_imgproc.CV_YUV2BGR_NV21);

            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageWidth, imageHeight,Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
            bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(rgbimage.getByteBuffer());

            //Save file to SDCARD------------

            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    "rgbbitmap.png");
            FileOutputStream fOut;
            try {
                fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
                fOut.flush();
                fOut.close();
                // mybitmap.recycle();

            } catch (Exception e) { // TODO

            }       


            try {

                // Get the correct time
                recorder.setTimestamp(videoTimestamp);

                // Record the image into FFmpegFrameRecorder
                recorder.record(yuvimage);

            } catch (FFmpegFrameRecorder.Exception e) {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

As well as, find the below bitmap image as I'm getting as output with 4 parts of same frame.

[image]

What's wrong with my code or what's missing by me? Let me know your best suggestions.

Thanks,

Comment: The camera preview data is usually in YUV format, so we need to convert that to RGB, with something like I've shown in the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12870556/523744

Comment: @SamuelAudet : Hi samuel thanks for your response. But it is not working. For your solution I have to take bitmap object with the config RGB_565 because we have created IPLImage with channel 3. N it is giving output image as I have updated.

Comment: @SamuelAudet : Kindly check my updated code and image.

Comment: @SamuelAudet : I have to use bitmap forcefully to RGB_565 , I can't use ARGB_8888. But I think we can take quality of bitmap using ARGB_8888 only.

Comment: `cvCvtColor()` also supports conversions like `CV_BGR2BGR565`, so try those out.

Comment: @SamuelAudet : yup but mostly I wanna convert it into ARGB so we can manage quality of it. If we will take RGB_565 bitmap, I can solve out everything. but the major concern is want to convert that iplimage to ARGB so I can create bitmap with ARGB_8888

Answer (score 0):

```
IplImage yuvImage = IplImage.create(width, height * 3 / 2, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
yuvImage.getByteBuffer().put(data);
IplImage bgrImage = IplImage.create(width, height, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
cvCvtColor(yuvImage, bgrImage, CV_YUV2BGR_NV21);
cvSaveImage("/mnt/sdcard/result.jpg", bgrImage);
```